# How to read browser status bar text in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox3.6

Is there anyone know how to read FireFox Browser Status bar text using Selenium WebDriver? I want it because I want to know whether my entire webpage is loaded completely or not.

Please suggest me if there is another way to do. Calling any JavaScript (which will be returning me Firefox Status bar text from my Java program)?

Also, how can I verify the presence of webelement I am looking on the webpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to read the FireFox Status bar using WebDriver.

When you do `webdriver.get()`, it will wait until the “onload” event has fired before returning control to your test or script.  However, that might not be good enough if your page uses a lot of AJAX to load content on your page and the "onload" event fires while stuff is still showing up in the browser.

If you need to ensure such pages are fully loaded then the solution is to use “waits”.

You can wait for a particular element:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("target")));
```

see: http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/selenium-2-examples/

Or try to wait for Ajax to complete any pending requests:

see: http://blog.activelylazy.co.uk/2010/05/05/testing-asynchronous-applications-with-webdriver/

Comment: Selenium 2 has implicit waits, which means that simply using `findElement` will wait until the target element is present and visible.

Comment: @Dave, what if that element does not shown up? will it throw some exception for not finding that element?

Comment: you are right. I am facing the issue when i am collecting search results from google. Now i think it is using Ajex and because of it my script is failing. For now I am temporary using simple `while loop` - `while(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Google Home")) == null && 
driver.findElements(By.linkText("About Google")) == null && 
driver.findElements(By.linkText("Advertising Programs")) == null) { driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); }`